# Where in the code can i find the connections between different screens?

Tags: expression-blend, sketchflow

I am going to expand an existing sketchflow application. The problem is that the person who created it didn't understood how component screens work. This means that instead of having one connection to the menu, every screen has one connection to every item that the menu is linked to. To solve this i implemented a component screen...the problem is that the connections still exists in the "sketchflow map" even tho there aint a connection in the application anymore. This makes it impossible to follow the applications flow.

Is there any way to go into the code files and remove the connections the hard way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connections are stored in XML in the Sketch.flow file. There is no supported way to remove them programitcally, but the file format is xml and is fairly straightforward. If you are familiar with XML you should be able to do it.